# log4j2 Logs not writing to file when running as jar

Tags: log4j2

I have configured log4j2.xml within eclipse and all logs write correctly to a file.
When I export maven project as a jar and run from command promt the logs are displayed on the console instead of writing to a file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace">
<Appenders>
<Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
</Console>
<File name="file_all" fileName="C:/log/logsALL.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
</File>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
<Root level="ERROR">
<AppenderRef ref="file_all"/>
</Root>

<Logger name="com.api.main" level="INFO">
<AppenderRef ref="file_all"/>
</Logger>       
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

When log4j starts up, it shows internal logging on the console (because status=trace in the configuration).
This internal log should show the location of the config file that is being used. Double-check that this is the correct location: I suspect that an old config file is being loaded that logs to the console...